# IBM-MQ Message Arrived Event Listener in Java

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Spec : IBMMQ 7.x, Jdk1.7,TOMCAT7,WINOS-7

Question : A Listener Event to continuously monitor Queue on specified IBM-MQ and alert/trigger/notify me that a 'x no of fresh messages' is available  for consumption.

Problem : 'For-Loop'  or Timer or Cron is NOT - Permitted to monitor the Queue for new messages.

Advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead why not setup a message listener and consume messages as and when they arrive? Your applications message listener will get invoked when a message arrives in a queue.

Here is sample code:

```
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);

        // Create connection factory
        cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
        // Set MQ properties
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM1");
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT,1414);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "MY.SVRCONN");           
        System.out.println("Connection Factory created.");

        connection = cf.createConnection();
        System.out.println("Connection created.");

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        System.out.println("Session created.");

        Destination destination = session.createQueue("SUB.Q");
        System.out.println("Destination created: " + destination.toString());
        consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        System.out.println("Consumer created.");
        // Now receive messages asynchronously
        // Create and register a new MessageListener for this consumer
        consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
          public void onMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                // Display the message that just arrived
                //System.out.println(msg);
                TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage)msg;
                System.out.println(txtMsg.getText());
            } // end try
            catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Exception caught in onMessage():\n" + e);
            }
            return;
          } // end onMessage()
        }); // end setMessageListener               
        connection.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        session.close();
```

Comment: >>why not setup a message listener    How can u do this in my code ~ java , please provide ref url or sample code to validate the same.

Comment: Look into the MessageListener JMS sample shipped with IBM MQ. You can find the samples under Mq install directory.

Comment: Sir ..Code provided above is for 1 time message consumption...correct me if wrong...I already have that code and need the same to continuously event monitor the Listener for fresh messages as available ...  "For-Loop' or Timer or Cron is NOT - Permitted to monitor the Queue for new messages."

Comment: No, it's not one message. The method waits for 5 seconds for the MessageListener to receive as many messages. You need to modify the sample code to run the MessageListener as long as you want.